# Git deployment in Azure Web App (Linux)

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I configured git deployment option in Azure Web App on Linux. Git clone URL is like "https://{username}@{webappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/{webappame}.git". The username is same as I set in "Deployment Credential" option. Same case with the password.
But each time I try to do "git push -u azuretestgit master" or "git clone {url}"I am getting an error as "fatal: unable to access. The requested URL returned error: 403"

Just FYI, I have added username, email, origin URL in Git using respective commands.

Comment: If you go to https://{app}.scm.azurewebsites.net/basicauth in the browser and use the same creds, does it work?

Comment: No. It loads page with message as ""No route registered for /<appname>.git"

Comment: You're trying the wrong url. Please reread my previous comment.

Comment: @DavidEbbo "Error 403 - This web app is stopped." But if i browse the appusing url i.e. "https://<app name>.azurewebsites.net/" it is working fine. Even when i checked Quota it shows Threshold "50 GB" and used is "0 kb".

Comment: Did you get this right away, or did it prompt for credential? Getting 403 is a sign that the user doesn't have sufficient access to the app. Does it work if you use the site credentials instead? Please see [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials) for details.

Comment: It prompts for credentials first. I am looking into link you shared. Will update you in few minutes

Comment: @DavidEbbo I was able to do git push & pull now using credentials provided in Publish profile i.e. username as $<appname> and password in Publish profile. But now the question is what is the use of Deployment credentials (that we create from settings blade) when we can not use in both git and ftp (as it is mentioned in their description)?

Comment: I don't understand your question "what is the use of Deployment credentials". Obviously, it works for most people, and you're having a very specific issue that is not yet identified. Going from there to question the use of the feature as a whole is quite a stretch :)

Comment: @DavidEbbo I agree with your comment. But in my case, deployment credentials are not working for both of the specified features i.e. FTP  and GIT. And it is strange. Can you please help me to identify the issue? I tried every possible combination of username just to test like <deployment username> <appname>\$<deployment username> , $<deployment username> , <appname>\<deployment username>  etc.

Comment: It's hard to tell more without site details. It would be best to open a support case to have it investigated.